# Access Form Input - Auto-Fill as User Passes Data

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating an access database that requires I have a separate column for each of the following three fields (which are related to my question): First name, last name, full name (syntax: "last, first").

I was wondering if there was a way that I could have a hidden input field (which would be the "full name" field). This hidden field would be filled with the data the user types in for "first name" and "last name", and would parse to the database all the same. Is this possible using basic Forms in Microsoft Access? Could I code the value for the field to be the user's input.

TIA!

Comment: This is certainly possible but I would recommend you not saving the full name, which adds complication and creates data redundancy, which you always want to avoid in your database design. Just store first and last names and combine them when they are displayed or printed.

Comment: So, 1 column that stores First name, last name, full name and you want to know if you can have a hidden input field for what purpose? VBA can handle this quite easily with 3 different fields

Comment: @Invent-Animate No, these are 3 separate columns. Technically one of them (full name) is being sent to a completely different database, but that is irrelevant for the sake of this question. The hidden input field would just easily pass data without the user having to input redundant information.

Comment: *"I am creating an access database that requires I have a column for the following three fields "* - What is that saying then?

Comment: @Invent-Animate I apologize, that was very poorly worded. I altered my original statement to be "I am creating an access database that requires I have a separate column for each of the following three fields"

Comment: With VBA, you can fire that information off at any point, really. You just need to determine at what point are *you sure* that they have filled out the information and won't make any changes before you send it? VBA can concatenate the 2 strings together and send it, but when are you going to call this method?

Comment: @Invent-Animate I was going to make a macro that would combine the names when the user presses the submit button, then parse all data. If this isn't a very good way of doing it, could you point me in the right direction as to what I should do?

Comment: If you have a form with First Name (named firstName) & Last Name(named lastName) text box controls, and a submit button on that form, in VBA you can reference the values in those fields and do with them what you please. If you need an example let me know, and I'll throw an answer together

Comment: @Invent-Animate If you could that would be great! I'll start working on it and use it as reference. I appreciate the help!

Comment: If your Access version is 2010 or later, you could use its calculated field type or data macro feature.  Either technique could maintain full name even for data changes made from outside your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, if you have 2 inputs for `First Name` and `Last Name`, we can utilize VBA to simply concatenate our strings for us.

For this example, I named my textboxes `txtFirstName` and `txtLastName`, respectively.

I then created a button to simulate your Submit button click, and here's the code to create the full name. What you do with it is up to you.

```
Dim FirstName, LastName, FullName As String

FirstName = Me.txtFirstName
LastName = Me.txtLastName

FullName = LastName & ", " & FirstName
Debug.Print FullName  'Optional; just to show you results
```

[image]

Comment: This makes sense, but it isn't parsing to my database upon click of the submit button. Would you know why?

Comment: Well, there's a few possibilities. Did you create new text boxes to accommodate my answer? Were you using any VBA before? What changes did you make? What isn't it doing that you need it to?

Comment: Did you add `Option Explicit` to the module's Declarations section and then run Debug->Compile and fix any problems the compiler complained about?

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of assigning the values to `FullName` (the title of the Column) I was supposed to assign them to the name of the textbox. Very new to VBA, so still learning. Thanks Invnet, everything is good now!

Comment: Oh, yeah - I didn't know that was the name of your column!